# adding items to a set in python

Tags: python

I want to create a set of roll no. of students
So I input the total no. of students and then input each roll no.

here is the code:

```
a=int(input())
s1=set()
for i in range(0,a):
  num=int(input())
  s1.add(num)
```

but when I run the code and input values I get this error

```
9

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vepul\eclipse-workspace\demo\dash.py", line 4, in <module>
    num=int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'
```

Comment: The problem doesn't have anything to do with adding items to a set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking your code to `int()` the string `"1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"`.

This won't work as there are spaces between the numbers, meaning it can't be cast to an integer.

When it asks for an input, you need to enter **one** integer, not all of them.
It will loop round (10 times in this case) to ask for a number; each time, you need to enter an integer.

If you're hoping to add all 9 integers in **one** go, try this:

```
s1 = set(map(int, input().split())) ## Make sure you enter the integers space-separated
```